# Set background color of headers and footers

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been able to change the background color of Word tables in the body of the document with: `oSourceTable.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdRed`. However, the same code does not work for header or footer Word tables. I have also tried setting the Section back color as well, but to no avail. The code runs, but the Headers and Footers are always displayed with white backgrounds.

I have done mostly Excel VBA, and only a little bit of Word VBA so maybe I am missing something obvious here. Thanks in advance for any ideas and/or suggestions.

As requested, here is the code I am using. vTableBackColors is just an array of colors. This code is for the body tables and is working perfectly.

```
For Each oWordTable In oWordDoc.Tables
    lIndex = lIndex + 1
    oWordTable.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = vTableBackColors(lIndex)
Next
```

I tried to do the same thing for the header and footer tables, but it does not work. I tried using the Header/Footer tables as below.

```
For Each oWordSection In oWordDoc.Sections
    For Each oWordTable In oWordSection.Headers.Item(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables
        ' I selected this one to see if it would make a difference.
        oWordTable.Select
        oWordTable.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = m_HeaderBackColor
    Next
    For Each oWordTable In oWordSection.Footers.Item(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables
        oWordTable.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = m_FooterBackColor
    Next
Next
```

I also tried using the Section Headers / Footers directly. Before and after checking shows that the BackgroundPatternColor has changed as desired, but it is not displayed.

```
oWordSection.Headers.Item(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = m_HeaderBackColor
```

[image]

Here is a screenshot showing the colorized body tables and the unchanged header.
Is it possible that, unlike the Body table colors, the Header / Footer colors are never displayed as such by the Word designer, but are only true at runtime?

Thanks for any additional information.

Comment: Can you post the complete code for what you are trying to do.  In particular how are you obtaining the OSourceTable value.

Comment: «the same code does not work for header or footer Word tables» It does if you reference them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

«I have been able to change the background color of Word tables in the body of the document with: oSourceTable.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = red.» That would not work unless you have defined 'red' as an RGB value.

As for the header/footer issue, this works for me:

```
For Each oWordSection In oWordDoc.Sections
    For Each oWordTable In oWordSection.Headers.Item(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables
        oWordTable.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdRed
    Next
    For Each oWordTable In oWordSection.Footers.Item(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables
        oWordTable.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdRed
    Next
Next
```

Perhaps your underlying problem is in the value you have assigned to 'm_HeaderBackColor' and 'm_FooterBackColor' - which your posted code doesn't show. It's also possible your code is addressing the wrong headers/footers (i.e. maybe it's not the primary ones you need to address).

Comment: Thanks, all of the colors are longs that came from Excel using ActiveCell.Interior.Color via the Background color picker. If I only define 1 header and footer via Insert Header and Insert Footer in the Designer ribbon, would that not be the primary header and footer?

Comment: So have you checked what the actual values of 'm_HeaderBackColor' and 'm_FooterBackColor' are when they get to your Word 'For Each oWordTable' loops? The header/footer issue depends on whether you have the page layout configured with the 'different first page' and/or 'different odd and even' layouts and, if so, which page you were on at the time. If the code in my answer works for you, that suggests the issue is indeed with the values of 'm_HeaderBackColor' and 'm_FooterBackColor'; otherwise, it's most likely to do with the page layout.